# How to install lxml.etree directly to web2py modules?

Tags: python, installation, web2py, web2py-modules, xml.etree

I have a working setup of lxml.etree working on my windows desktop.

Since I wanted to move this to my server, instead of installing lxml in sitepackages, I wanted to install it inside the `modules` directly, so this `lxml` version is specific to this applicaion/site.

I copied my lxml directory directly under modules on the linux server, and I got this error :

**No module named etree**

So it seems it understood there is an `lxml`, package but couldn't see `etree` inside it.
Any ideas ?
Also, I couldn't find exactly where I can download the binaries for ubuntu 9.10 on the site : http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just copy the Windows version over to a Linux server; `lxml` uses C extensions which need to be compiled for the target platform.

The `etree` module is such a compiled extension, on Linux that'd be `etree.so`, while on Windows it would be a `etree.dll` file instead, for example.

For Ubuntu, look for [`python-lxml`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-lxml), or install the dependencies [`libxml2-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxml2-dev), [`libxslt1-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxslt1-dev) and [`python-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-dev), plus [`python-pip`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pip), then use `sudo pip install lxml` to install `lxml` on your server.

Comment: so even after compiling I cant install it only for web2py ?

Comment: you could install it only for web2py, yes.